# Ubuntu Server 12.04: upgraded php to 5.4, now sites won't load

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php5

I just upgraded php on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 to 5.4 from 5.3, using the `ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable` ppa but now my php-powered sites don't load (I just get a downloaded file). I've restarted `apache2`, and my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
#    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
#       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
# To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#            php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

There's nothing in apache's error.log:

```
[Tue Feb 10 15:55:13 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 15:55:14 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Tue Feb 10 15:55:14 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Feb 10 15:55:14 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Feb 10 15:55:14 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.4.37-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2011-06-30) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

`apache2ctl configtest` gives this output:

```
[Tue Feb 10 16:23:42 2015] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf.d/owncloud.conf.old at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Tue Feb 10 16:23:42 2015] [warn] NameVirtualHost 2001:41D0:2:6D94::1:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Feb 10 16:23:42 2015] [warn] NameVirtualHost 94.23.234.148:443 has no VirtualHosts
```

I've also ensured the php5 mod is enabled with `a2endmod php` (it says it's already enabled). Obviously there was some sort of configuration change between 5.3 and 5.4 but I can't find what it was using Google-fu.

Weirdly, OwnCloud works, which is why I upgraded to 5.4 in the first place (v8 requires it). It's build in PHP and executes fine!

If I put a php file in `/var/www` it works, so the problem is obviously with my virtual hosts.

Any help much appreciated!

Laurence

Comment: What is the Apache error.log giving you? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Have updated the question. No there's nothing unusual in there.

Comment: Added some more about Owncloud working (which is built in PHP)

Comment: Added the output of `apache2ctl configtest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by disabling the `php5_cgi` Apache module, as per this thread over on Virtualmin's forums: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/25521